Is there an exwm function to read the state of the plugged in monitors?
Below is my basic randr setup for exwm on my laptop and it places the laptop screen to the left, so I usually drag floating panes there to view them.
However when I unplug the external monitor screen the output does not switch to the laptop screen, so I have to log out of EXWM and restart the session for the output to appear on the laptop screen.
Is there a function I can use to check the state of the plugged in screens when the exwm-randr-screen-change-hook occurs ?
I think I should be able to use the info to set the outputs using setq exwm-randr-workspace-output-plist?
  (require 'exwm-randr)
  (setq exwm-randr-workspace-output-plist '(0 "HDMI-1" 1 "HDMI-1" 2 "HDMI-1" 3 "HDMI-1" 4 "HDMI-1" 5 "HDMI-1" 6 "HDMI-1" 7 "HDMI-1" 8 "HDMI-1" 9 "HDMI-1" ))
  (add-hook 'exwm-randr-screen-change-hook
            (lambda ()
              (start-process-shell-command
               "xrandr" nil "xrandr --output eDP-1 --right-of HDMI1-1 --auto")))

